# Collection view last item right aligned

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I have a list of items in a horizontal collection view. Is it possible to align the last item in a collection view always to the right irrespective of how many items are there in the list?
Example :

```
[ item1 item2 item3 item4      item5]   
[ item1 item2                  item5]
```

`item5` always remains to the right.

Is it possible to keep all items as a part of a single section of the collection view in this case or essentially keep in two different sections and also in that case how would then the insets on the sections be set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout). [Here](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Collection-View-Guide) is an example but you must tailor it to your need. (I see from your example that you may also have to set a custom contentSize).

Comment: Thanks.Will check into that.